# Last values are not getting stored in an array in session in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have a page with many like buttons against many images, as I am clicking the like button, the id of the individual image is sent to the controller and in the controller I am storing these values in the session variable in an array.

```
$this->load->library("session");
$id_image = $this->input->post('ids');
$image_id_session =  $this->session->userdata('likes');
if (!is_array($image_id_session)){
        $image_id_session = array();
   }
$image_id_session[]=$id_image;
$this->session->set_userdata('likes',$image_id_session);
```

The problem is I am just getting the current image id, all other past ids in the current session are not getting stored in the array.

Comment: can u show the value of `print_r($id_image);`

Comment: https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bmimagedump/uploads/interior/design/1531557190.jpg

Comment: for the session variable likes I am getting 
    Array
(
    [0] => https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bmimagedump/uploads/interior/design/1531557792.jpg
)

Comment: The image ids are different because they are two different images, one is 1531557190 and in the other case it is 1531557792. I clicked on two different images, that's why.

Comment: What I am looking for is all the ids one after another in the array, under the session variable likes.

Answer (score 0):

check `print_r($_SESSION);` If Value Is Saved Or Not

Comment: Yes, I did that and I am getting an array with the id of the last image only .

Comment: Can U Paste The Print_r Result Here

Comment: Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1533625128 [likes] => Array ( [0] => https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/bmimagedump/uploads/interior/design/1531557905.jpg ) )